# Faster math ops

Tags: java, performance, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fast algorithm for polar -> cartesian conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289644/fast-algorithm-for-polar-cartesian-conversion)

I am running some pathfinding code (which is a bit slow) through jvisualvm, what I found was that 80% time is being spent in my vector implementation more specifically the part that convert cartesian to polar,

```
r = Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
t = Math.atan2(y,x);
```

are there any old school tricks that would get me some more performance?

Comment: @PaulTomblin but this is the other way around...

Answer (score 7):

In my experience in path finding algorithms, the problem is not those lines.

The main questions is *"How many times you call these two lines?"*

You should investigate your path finding algorithm.

Anyway, if you want reduce the delay of those lines, it is possible to make a pre-calculated table for `sqrt` and `atan2` for each `x` and `y`. Or even a table that maps each (x, y) to (r, t) directly.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider if you really need to use `Math.atan2()`.  In my experience there are very few geometric computations that really need the actual angle; you can get faster, simpler, and more robust results by using more natural operations.

For example, if you want to evaluate the angle between two vectors (say, `a` and `b`), you can instead often use the dot product:

```
(a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y) = |a| |b| cos(angle)
```

and a kind of rump "cross product":

```
(a.x*b.y - a.y*b.x) = |a| |b| sin(angle)
```

This "cross product" is especially useful because the sign tells you which side of vector `a` the vector `b` points to.

If it turns out you really *do* need an angle (usually for human-readable output), these values are tailor made for input to `atan2()`.