# Draw rectangles on circle formula

Tags: android, math

I'm trying to draw the spectrum of an audio file on a circle. Like this:

[image]

So on the circle I just want rectangles drawn like you see on the image.

I've got this code:

```
public void onRender(Canvas canvas, FFTData data, Rect rect) {
    canvas.drawCircle(rect.width()/2, rect.height()/2, 200, mPaint);

    for (int i = 0; i < data.bytes.length / mDivisions; i++) {
        byte rfk = data.bytes[mDivisions * i];
        byte ifk = data.bytes[mDivisions * i + 1];
        float magnitude = (rfk * rfk + ifk * ifk);
        int dbValue = (int) (10 * Math.log10(magnitude));


    }
}
```

Where FFTData is the Fast Fourier Transformation data that Android gives me. Now in my dbValue I got the strength of the signal. mDivisions is how much bars I want. Currently set on 16 because I don't know how much I can set on the circle.

I'm stuck on how I can draw the rectangle with his center on the circle line... So I want a rectangle whose height is based on the dbValue so that I get high and low rectangles. And the center must be placed on my circle line.

Can someone help me on this math formula?

Comment: i solved your problem by just one function that you passed the height of your rectangular and the degree from x axis and it draw it for you do you want it or your problem is solved.`mySpectrumDrawer(int centerX, int centerY,int R,int height, int angel)` http://i.imgur.com/bti4Sh3.jpg

Comment: Cool, I'm having all the same blocks right now, but I need to translate, rotate .. Can you maybe share your function here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think all you have needed is a pencil and a paper and a little math and also some free time to play :-)

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  ImageView drawingImageView;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawingImageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.DrawingImageView);

                Paint paint;
                paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(16);

               final  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

                int centerX =400;
                int centerY =400;
                int R = 200;

                canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, R, paint);

                int h = 100;

                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                Path p = new Path();
                p.moveTo(centerX + R - h/2, centerY);
                p.lineTo(centerX + R + h/2, centerY);
                canvas.drawPath(p, paint);

                p = mySpectrumDrawer(centerX,centerY,R,h,15);
                canvas.drawPath(p, paint);

                h = 50;
                p = mySpectrumDrawer(centerX,centerY,R,h,30);
                canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
                h = 60;   
                p = mySpectrumDrawer(centerX,centerY,R,h,60);
                canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
                h = 80;
                p = mySpectrumDrawer(centerX,centerY,R,h,90);
                canvas.drawPath(p, paint);

                drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } 

  private Path mySpectrumDrawer(int centerX, int centerY,int R,int height, int angel){

        Path p = new Path();

        int dX = (int) (R*(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angel))));
        int dY = (int) (R*(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angel))));

        int dhx = (int) (height/2*(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angel))));
        int dhy = (int) (height/2*(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angel))));

        p.moveTo(centerX + dX - dhx , centerY - dY + dhy);
        p.lineTo(centerX + dX + dhx , centerY - dY - dhy);

        return p;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Works. I was so close. I just had my dhX and dHy wrong :p. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

Run a loop over all 360 degrees of the circle (at wanted step), and, for each point, convert Polar (this angle and the radius of the circle) coordinates into Cartesian, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289644/fast-algorithm-for-polar-cartesian-conversion), for instance. This way you get the location of the centre of your rectangle.

[Translate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#translate%28float,%20float%29) the system of the coordinates, making origin to be at the wanted point on the circle line and then [rotate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate%28float%29) by the circle angle at that point.

Alternatively, you can build a trapezoid by getting corners at angle +- some offset and radius +- some offset (proportional to your value to plot). It will have shorter inner edge and longer outer edge. Such trapezoids may look better if painted side by side.

Comment: Have you got any pseudocode or something. I'm not so good in maths.

Comment: How can I run over the degrees of the circle? Or do you just mean a forloop from 0 to 360?

Comment: Yes, exactly. for (double angle=0; angle < 360; angle += 10) for instance.