# Faster way to go from cartesian to polar in C?

Tags: math, fft, polar-coordinates

My C code for discrete Fourier transform needs to output polar values, `amplitude` and `angle`. I have a fast algorithm that outputs cartesian values, `x` and `y`.

Is there a faster way of converting (f.e. 1024) cartesian values to polar than just:

```
int x, y;
float amplitude, angle;
...
amplitude = sqrt( x*x + y*y);
angle = atan2( y, x );
```

?

Comment: I'm sure that this converting is much faster than FFT. So there is no reason to worry about it's speed. Have you measured and compared elapsed time?

Comment: @MBo Yes, I'll do the measurement next, thanks. Hopefully, it will be much faster than FFT itself, in which case I'll live with it.

Comment: Use [`amplitude = hypot(x, y)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/hypot.html) if available on your platform.

Comment: Be aware that atan2 returns nan if both of its arguments are 0. Of course the angle is undefined in this case, and maybe nan is what you want..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast algorithm for polar -> cartesian conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289644/fast-algorithm-for-polar-cartesian-conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches:

(1) Perform the common 2D FFT, and then complete the cartesian to polar conversion by yourself.

(2) Use the so called "polar FFT" directly. Actually, the "polar FFT" is also based on the interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you read about [CORDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC), check out this [article](http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4007665/Speeding-up-the-CORDIC-algorithm-with-a-DSP).